# Polymer core-label and core-checkbox dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm trying to generate a list of `core-label` elements with javascript.

In the documentation(https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-label) it is written, that I may add the attribute `for` in an input-element inside the `core-label` to connect them.

If I code it static like this, it is possible:

```
<core-label>
     <core-image></core-image>
     <paper-checkbox for></paper-checkbox>
     <span>Text</span>
</core-label>
```

But if i try to add those elements dynamic inside a script, those elements are not connected...

```
    var catLayout = document.createElement("core-label");
    var img = document.createElement("core-image");
    var chk = document.createElement("paper-checkbox");
    chk.setAttribute("for","");
    var label = document.createElement("span");
    var labelcontent = document.createTextNode("text");
    label.appendChild(labelcontent);
    catLayout.appendChild(img);
    catLayout.appendChild(chk);
    catLayout.appendChild(label);
```

May anyone tell me, whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing should work. I wonder if you're running into a timing issue due to the way you're script is being executed within the larger context of your application. But here's a functionally equivalent snippet that does the job:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <script src="//www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/core-label/core-label.html">
    <link rel="import" href="//www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
    
    <div>
      <core-label>
       <paper-checkbox for></paper-checkbox>
       <span>Created via Markup</span>
      </core-label>
    </div>
    
    <div id="container"></div>
    
    <script>
      var coreLabel = document.createElement('core-label');
      var paperCheckbox = document.createElement('paper-checkbox');
      paperCheckbox.setAttribute('for', '');
      var text = document.createElement('span');
      text.textContent = 'Created via JavaScript';
      coreLabel.appendChild(paperCheckbox);
      coreLabel.appendChild(text);
      document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(coreLabel);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That being said, I'm curious as to *why* you need to create these elements via JavaScript. I personally find Polymer code much easier to read and maintain when as much as possible is handled via the DOM using Polymer's `<template>` logic. For instance, if you're resorting to JavaScript element creation because you want to include these elements conditionally, wrapping `<template if="{{your_condition}}">` around that section of your DOM could take care of that for you. Similarly, if you're doing this from JavaScript because you want to repeat the logic multiple times for each element in an array, `<template repeat="{{item in your_array}}">` can handle that for you. The [data-binding section of the docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html) is great if you haven't seen it.

Comment: I did not work with repeat before, but it works perfekt and looks much better. Thank You!